# Помогите, не могу получить данные с json через axios

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, axios

Скажите пожалуйста почему я не могу получить локальные данные с .json файла через axios
db.json находится в корне проекта, пытался его переместить в папку public но в функции getEvents() выкидывает ошибку 404
Что я сделал не так?

operation.js

```js
import FetchClient from 'app/utils/FetchClient';
import IdsAndByIds from 'app/utils/IdsAndByIds';
import { eventsFetch, setEvents } from './actions';

export const getEvents = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await FetchClient.get('./db.json');
    dispatch(setEvents(IdsAndByIds(data)));
    dispatch(eventsFetch(false));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

FetchClient.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { URL_API } from 'app/config'; //localhost:3009

const FetchClient = () => {
  const defaultOptions = {
    baseURL: URL_API,
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  const instance = axios.create(defaultOptions);
  return instance;
};

export default FetchClient();
```

actions.js

```js
import * as types from './types';

export const eventsFetch = value => ({
  type: types.FETCHING_EVENTS,
  payload: value
});

export const setEvents = ({ objById, arrayIds }) => ({
  type: types.SET_EVENTS,
  payload: {
    eventById: objById,
    eventsOrder: arrayIds
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: По моему точка перед db.json не нужна. Т.е. надо писать FetchClient.get('/db.json'). Иначе получается что вы пытаетесь запросить адрес localhost:3009/./db.json

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис попробовал, тоже не выходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь напрямую к json файлу, а так вы не получите данные. Для работы с axios нужен запрос на URL.. подключите json-server/https://github.com/typicode/json-server и через него передавайте данные с вашего json файла в компонент использую axios.

Comment: cпасибо, помогло